# How to prevent duplication of values in local storage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, logic

I'm coding a shopping cart with local storage support but it's not working properly. When i increment or decrement, i have an if-else statement to handle whether if the item is in the basket or not as shown below:

```js
let basket = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data")) || [];
.
.
.
let increment = (id) => {
    let selectedItem = id;
    const itemId = selectedItem[1].id;

    let currentItem = shopItemsData.find(item => item.id === itemId);

    //checking if the object already exists
    if(basket.includes(currentItem)) {
        currentItem['itemCount'] += 1;
        selectedItem[1].innerText = currentItem['itemCount'];
    } else {
        basket.push(currentItem);
        currentItem['itemCount'] = 1;
        selectedItem[1].innerText = currentItem['itemCount'];
    }
    updateCart();
    localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(basket));
}
```

At first it works normally and the items got saved in the local storage but every time i reload and click on the same item it duplicates the object and the count starts again from zero.

[Visual Explanation of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OL5S.gif)

Comment: Clear/reset then re-push your object of data each time

Comment: What's the reason for renaming the parameter variable? If you want it to be called `selectedItem`, then use `(selectedItem) => { ... }`

Comment: `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data")) || [];` - The `|| []` won't save you when that `.parse()` fails

Comment: Like Andreas said you need `let basket = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data") || "[]");`

Comment: Main issue: `basket.includes(currentItem)` is never true after a reload because once you reload the basket (which is stored as a string) the memory reference is gone and includes() checks for actual identity. You need to do the same as with shopItemsData: compare the id. In other words: `[{ id: 1 }].includes({ id: 1 })` is `false` because it's not the same object in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short version

You should compare using a method like [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) as referenced values can't directly be compared despite them having the same structure.

For example :

```
    // ... Omitting the rest for brevity
    const basketItem = basket.find((item) => item.id === id);

    if(basketItem) {
        basketItem['itemCount'] += 1;
        currentItem['itemCount'] = basketItem['itemCount']
        selectedItem[1].innerText = basketItem['itemCount'];
    } else {
        basket.push(currentItem);
        currentItem['itemCount'] = 1;
        selectedItem[1].innerText = currentItem['itemCount'];
    }

    // ... Omitting the rest for brevity
```

## Slightly longer explanation

The issue is that you're looking for a different reference of an object. Javascript has 2 different ways of comparing and representing data: by reference or by value. This is common across other programming languages, but it's usually a lot more explicit than in JS. A very simple way to think about it is that primitives (string, booleans, numbers) are usually compared by value. More complex structures (Date, Array, Object) are compared by their reference, like a pointer in memory.

Here's a couple of examples :

```
const str1 = 'string';
const str2 = 'string';
console.log(str1 === str2); // true as they are both primitives and they represent the same value.

const obj1 = { obj: 1 };
const obj2 = { obj: 1 };
console.log(obj1 === obj2); // false as they are referenced values and point to different objects despite the value being the same.

// Now to compare with your issue.
const arr = [obj1];
console.log(arr.includes(obj1)); // true
console.log(arr.includes(obj2)); // false as obj2 isn't in the array despite the value of obj2 being the same as obj1.
```

Comment: I changed the `.includes()` method to the `find()` method as you mentioned in the short version of your explanation but now the "itemCount" is giving me `NaN` and i don't have a clear idea of how to turn it into a number if i parsed the basket.

Comment: I've updated the portion in my example related to if an element is in your basket which should avoid a NaN. With the snippet it's hard to understand where the error might be. It seems like you might have some structure issues in your code. Notably, you don't have a single source of truth for your basket. You seem to hold data for your basket in both the basket and shopItemsData objects. You might be able to simplify your code if you only have one variable holding basket related contents.